# How can i create a (design time only) nuget package that doesn't add an assembly reference when installed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, code-analysis, nuspec

I want to build a `nuget` package  for a design time only package. This package contains resources (a ruleset file, a build props file and an assembly) for using a custom code analysis rule set.

My nuspec file (inside my `CodeAnalysis` assembly project) looks like this:

```
<package>
    <metadata>
        <id>$id$</id>
        <version>$version$</version>
        <authors>$author$</authors>
        <description>$description$</description>
        <references>
        </references>
        <developmentDependency>true</developmentDependency>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <!-- copy rules assembly to tools folder -->
        <file src="bin\Release\CodeAnalysis.dll" target="tools\CodeAnalysis.dll" />
        <file src="tools\CodeAnalysis.ruleset" target="tools\CodeAnalysis.ruleset" />
        <file src="build\CodeAnalysis.props" target="build\CodeAnalysis.props" />
    </files>
</package>
```

When in build this package, the `CodeAnalysis.dll` assembly is present in `\lib\net40\CodeAnalysis.dll`, and a copy is added in `\tools\CodeAnalysis.dll`.

When i use this package in another project, the default behavior is that a reference to the assembly is added to the project. Since this a a design / build time only assembly (only used when executing code analysis on the project), i don't want `nuget` to add this reference.

I've looked into the `<references>` section of the `nuspec` file, but that doesn't give me a clue how to prevent a reference from being made.

**How do i build a nuspec file so that nuget does not add a project reference when installing the nuget package?**

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [ConditionalAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) class in the [System.Diagnostics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.aspx) namespace. With this you can specify a conditional compilation symbol that if isn't defined the target of the `[Conditional]` attribute isn't compiled into the resulting assembly.

This way you could define a `CODE_ANALYSIS` symbol (or whatever name you choose) and decorate all the types, methods, properties, etc. in your project with the `[Conditional("CODE_ANALYSIS")]` attribute. If people using your package haven't also defined this symbol then their resulting compiled assembly will not include a reference to your project, but they will be able to benefit from it at design time.

This is what [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/) use for their [Annotations NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JetBrains.Annotations/), there's a [blog post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/08/12/how-to-use-jetbrains-annotations-to-improve-resharper-inspections/) about it here:

http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/08/12/how-to-use-jetbrains-annotations-to-improve-resharper-inspections/

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `-tool` command line switch to nuget. This will not include the DLL as a referenced assembly.

```
nuget pack MyProject.csproj -tool
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify this in the nuspec file? (i'm building directly from visual studio)

Comment: Using a Visual Studio extension?

Comment: Can you give the full example? What is pack? That the package name?